# is there a theorem which describes why this creates a right angle?

Tags: geometry, circles, triangles, angle

> draw circle A 
> draw smaller circle B such that it passes through center of circle A and intersects circle A at two points (E1 & E2) 
> draw a diameter of circle A that passes through center point of circle B; label points on edge of circle A: I=point that lies inside circle B, F=point that does not 
> now when you draw two straight lines IE1 and FE1, you get a right angle 
WHY?!  I want to understand why this is!  Can someone point to a theorem where I can explore this idea in greater depth?  I have searched and searched with the search terms I can think to use and I keep getting information about orthogonal circles, which is obviously not what I'm looking for.

see the image here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjfe8.png

Comment: The circle B isn't even necessary for this. It seems like you're just looking for the fact that any angle that subtends a diameter is a right angle. This is called [Thales' theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thales%27s_theorem).

Comment: Yes!  Thank you!  I even stumped an astrophysicist on this one.  This is pretty basic, so even I should have known this (I think the smaller circle was a distraction).  But then neither of us has taken a geometry course in ages.  ;)  The point on the outside of circle A was located through the other circle, so it seemed important, but obviously wasn't.  Playing Euclidea and figured if I can't figure out the more complicated solution on such an early level (1.7) then I stand no chance later in the game.  Using the game to help brush up on my geometry skills in preparation for the general GRE.

Comment: @filamentary  
If you are ok, you can accept the answer and set as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes any angle subtended by a diameter is a right angle.

[image]

Comment: Yes, thank you.  I did want the name of the theorem, though.  Someone above mentioned that it was Thales' theorem.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thales%27s_theorem